# subtracting latitudes with NSNumber type to find distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber, cllocation

I want to subtract two latitudes from each other to find the shortest distance, but I get this error, "Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSNumber', which is not a constant size in non-fragile ABI"   If I change the - to a + I get a different error "Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSNumber *' and 'NSNumber *')"  I've tried using doubles and many combinations of things, but it just doesn't work.

```
NSNumber *userLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:43.55];//sample

NSArray *listOfCities = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    for (CityList *item in listOfCities){
        NSLog(@"latitude is %@",item.latitude);  
        NSNumber *distanceLat =  userLatitude - item.latitude;
```

I will then insert them into a mutable array along with the longitudes and compare the distance. One possible solution using CLLocation would be

```
double distance = [usersCurrentLoc distanceFromLocation:otherLoc];
```

where usersCurrentLoc and otherLoc are both CLLocation variables. 
I also want use the latitude and longitudes individually so I can do some custom plotting, and they are also stored separately, so I'd like to figure out the correct data types and most efficient solution.

item.latitude comes from core-data with the data model type of double and X-code auto generated the CityList class with a property of NSNumber * latitude;

Comment: are you trying to find the shortest distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want subtract two **NSNumbers**, then use this

```
NSNumber *distanceLat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([userLatitude floatValue] - [item.latitude floatValue])];
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
NSNumber *distanceLat =  userLatitude - item.latitude;
```

needs to be:

```
NSNumber *distanceLat = @([userLatitude doubleValue] - item.latitude);
```

If `item.latitude` is also an `NSNumber` then you need to call `doubleValue` on it too.

`NSNumber` is an object. You can't do math on the object. You need to use `doubleValue` to get its value and then you need to wrap the result in a new `NSNumber` instance.

BTW - why bother with `NSNumber` here? Why not do:

```
double userLatitude = 43.55;

double distanceLat = userLatitude - item.latitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = [newLocation coordinate];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D oldCoordinate = [oldLocation coordinate];
```

CLLocationDistance meters = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];

The above one can be used to find distance between two locations